# How to add a RequiredFieldValidator to DropDownList control?

Tags: asp.net, validation, drop-down-menu, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a `DropDownList` binded with a`SqlDataSource` to display the values from the database.

I am unable to validate using a `RequiredFieldValidator`.

Answer (score 106):

For the most part you treat it as if you are validating any other kind of control but use the InitialValue property of the required field validator.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="your-dropdownlist" InitialValue="Please select" ErrorMessage="Please select something" />
```

Basically what it's saying is that validation will succeed if any other value than the 1 set in InitialValue is selected in the dropdownlist.

If databinding you will need to insert the "Please select" value afterwards as follows

```
this.ddl1.Items.Insert(0, "Please select");
```

Comment: HI dude,

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="DropDownList1" ErrorMessage="select any value" 
                    InitialValue="Selectvalue" >*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

this is my code i am still unable to get the message when i submit the button

Comment: After databinding does your dropdownlist contain a value for "Selectvalue". I've edited my answer to show how.

Comment: @Fishcake, you need to have InitialValue="0". Everything else in your answer is good.

Comment: @strider this isn't true. If you follow what I posted and then inspect the generated HTML you get `<option value="Please select">Please select</option>` and so the InitialValue of "Please select" is correct.

Comment: If you populated it as follows: `ddl1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select", "0"));` then you would indeed need to set `InitialValue = "0"`

Comment: Instead of insert from codebehind I would add the top item this way: `<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDepo" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
<asp:ListItem Text="Please select" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>`

Comment: Or just leave out the "Please select" item and then you don't need a RequiredFieldValidator because an item will always be selected.

Comment: @MikeW Suddenly 90% of your customer base liives in Afghanistan ;)

Answer (score 31):

Suppose your drop down list is:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="ddl">
<asp:ListItem Value="0" text="Select a Value">
....
</asp:DropDownList>
```

There are two ways:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="re1" runat="Server" InitialValue="0" />
```

the 2nd way is to use a compare validator:

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="re1" runat="Server" ValueToCompare="0" ControlToCompare="ddl" Operator="Equal" />
```

Comment: If data binding, I think this was is still preferred over inserting into your list. You just have to change the DropDownList to support it. `<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="ddl" AppendDataBoundItems="true">`

Comment: Question: I am getting the ErrorMessage for my dropdown just fine by using the RequiredFieldValidator, however, when I then select from the dropdown, all of the other form classes, like my textboxes' error messages clear out along with the ddl's error message.

Comment: You forgot the ending `/` at the end of `<asp:ListItem ... />`.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using a data source, here's another way to do it without code behind.

Note the following key points:

- The `ListItem` of `Value="0"` is on the source page, not added in code
- The `ListItem` in the source will be overwritten if you don't include
  `AppendDataBoundItems="true"` in the `DropDownList`
- `InitialValue="0"` tells the validator that this is the value that
  should fire that validator (as pointed out in other answers)

Example:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlType" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsType"
                  DataValueField="ID" DataTextField="Name" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="--Please Select--" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvType" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlType" 
                            InitialValue="0" ErrorMessage="Type required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsType" runat="server" 
                   ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:TESTConnectionString %>'
                   SelectCommand="SELECT ID, Name FROM Type"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Best answer I have come across in my search for setting a initial value for a drop down list that uses an SQL Data Source.

Answer (score 1):

InitialValue="0" : initial validation will fire when 0th index item is selected in ddl.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator InitialValue="0" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="error" runat="server" ID="your_id" ValidationGroup="validationgroup" ControlToValidate="your_dropdownlist_id" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to check with empty string then use the following:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="REQUIREDFIELDVALIDATOR1" ControlToValidate="ControlId" runat="server" ValidationGroup="groupName" InitialValue="" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please select" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```