# How to add an initial "select" value to a DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

If I use a DropDownList:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListSubContractors" runat="server" 
     DataTextField="Company_Name" DataValueField="id">
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

What attribute do I use/set that allows me to use '---Select---' as initial option on the drop down, instead of the first value in the list.

Comment: I noticed comments about making sure the "--Select--" ListItem isn't selected. Here's how to require a different selection: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38727154/3347858

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListSubContractors" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataTextField="Company_Name" DataValueField="id">
    <asp:ListItem Text="---Select---" Value="0" />   
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Or you can add this dynamically at code behind like this

```
DropDownListSubContractors.Items.Add(new ListItem("---Select---", "0"));
```

Comment: Sorry about the delay in replying, but thanks for the answer. The program still runs if the user hasnt chosen anything from the drop down but still presses submit, how can I fix it so the user needs to select a value from the drop down before they cna click the button?Or they can still click the button but the code won't run and an error will display please select...

Comment: You can use either required or CustomValidator to prevent user to select the value from drop down. You can also validate this by javascript like if(document.getElementById("DropDownListSubContractors").value==0){alert('Please select value');}.

Answer (score 7):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListSubContractors" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataTextField="Company_Name" DataValueField="id">
    <asp:ListItem Text="---Select---" Value="" />   
</asp:DropDownList>
```

You could now bind your DropDown in the code behind as usual to the datasource and this data source doesn't need to contain a default value item:

```
IEnumerable<MyViewModel> model = ...
DropDownListSubContractors.DataSource = model;
DropDownListSubContractors.DataBind();
```

Comment: Sorry about the delay in replying, but thanks for the answer. The program still runs if the user hasnt chosen anything from the drop down but still presses submit, how can I fix it so the user needs to select a value from the drop down before they cna click the button? Or they can still click the button but the code won't run and an error will display please select...

Comment: You could use assign a Required validator to the dropdown: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280559/how-to-add-a-requiredfieldvalidator-to-dropdownlist-control

Answer (score 2):

You can do this this way:

From Code behind:

```
DropDownListSubContractors.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select---", string.Empty));
```

*Note: We use index 0 to make it the first element at the list.*

Comment: Sorry about the delay in replying, but thanks for the answer. The program still runs if the user hasnt chosen anything from the drop down but still presses submit, how can I fix it so the user needs to select a value from the drop down before they cna click the button? Or they can still click the button but the code won't run and an error will display please select...

Comment: John, consider adding a RequiredFieldValidator so the user won't be able to click the submit button without choosing from the selections