# Dynamically adding listitems to a select tag in ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, forms, html-select

I'm trying to do something I thought would be very simple - dynamically add some options in a select tag using ASP.NET.

I've written my code as:

```
<select id='cmbDuration'>
<%  Dim periods As Generic.List(Of Models.Duration) = DBSupport.getDurations
    For Each d As Models.Duration In periods
        Response.Write("<option value='" & d.id & "'>" & d.name & "</option>")        
    Next   
 %>
</select>
```

All is well and the data returned by my db layer appear in my select tag.

Later on, I remembered to add a `runat = "Server"` tag, to process my data in my code-behind post. But, after adding that, no options are displayed. Checking the resulting source code, I see no options added to it as well.

What is the problem here? Why no options are shown when `runat = "Server"` is added?

Comment: You should be using an [asp:DropDownList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686892/asp-drop-down-list)

Comment: That's understandable, but still, since even the `asp:DropDownList` is rendered as a `select` tag, why adding `runat="Server"` causes the code inside the loop not to render anything on the page?

Comment: You can't just add runat="server" to a rendered control like you are. you should think of it like your just rendering a load of strings (HTML) and this happens after the runat="server" tag is parsed. So you can either add a runat="server" tag and then add the options in the code behind or you can add a load of HTML and this isn't available in the code behind. You can't do both, which is what your trying to do.

Comment: So, the way I understand this, is that adding the `runat="Server"` attribute will result in my control being available for subsequent process only in code-behind. I tried the following, which proves this right: `<input type="checkbox" id="myId" runat="server"/><%  myId.Checked = True%>` - the code block is ignored and the checkbox remains unchecked. I have to change its checked state in code-behind. Thanks.

Comment: Added a more descriptive answer. It's about the difference in compile-time and runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, the way I understand this, is that adding the runat="Server"
>   attribute will result in my control being available for subsequent
>   process only in code-behind

No, adding `runat="server"` tells visual studio and the compiler that this control will be represented as a server control. It add's a server control into your `.designer.cs` file:

```
 /// <summary>
 /// Image3 control.
 /// </summary>
 /// <remarks>
 /// Auto-generated field.
 /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
 /// </remarks>
 protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image Image3;
```

this process happens at **design time**.

Your code (everything inside the `<%%>`) happens at **runtime**. So your trying to build dynamic HTML using your code block. So the designer has no idea what your going to add, *how many controls are your adding? How do I represent this?* So it can't build the server side control code. So it doesn't. It also causes the runtime code to be unable to process the [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx). Again it doesn't know what your controls are supposed to represent.

So you can't simply:

```
<select id='cmbDuration' runat='server'>
<%  Dim periods As Generic.List(Of Models.Duration) = DBSupport.getDurations
    For Each d As Models.Duration In periods
        Response.Write("<option value='" & d.id & "' runat='server'>" & d.name & "</option>")        
    Next   
 %>
</select>
```

This is simply invalid ASP.Net syntax. You can't write to the code behind at **runtime** in this manner. Before your for-loop is executed .Net has already built up what code behind blocks it needs, so you can't add to this.

I'm not going to repeat what @Scott has already answered but this is what you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you talking about processing data in your code-behind post, but writing in-line code to generate list items? You should be binding your dropdown list in the code-behind:

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:DropDown ID="cmbDuration" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" runat="server" />
```

CODE-BEHIND (in Page_Load)

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
    Dim periods As Generic.List(Of Models.Duration) = DBSupport.getDurations
    cmbDuration.DataSource = periods
    cmbDuration.DataBind()
End If
```

Comment: You are right of course, I was just wondering why adding the `runat="server"` attribute would result in my code in the loop not being executed at all. Liam's comment helped me understand this better.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are writing to ASPNET's "Response Stream" by using the function Response.Write(), which will cause the output'd option tags to appear at the very very top of the page where the Response Stream is printed. This will appear even above the HTML declaration tag. (Examine your HTML source code to see) If you wish to write output directly to the ASPX page, try this:

```
<select id='cmbDuration'>
    <%For x As Integer = 0 To 5%>
        <option><%=x%></option>
    <%Next%>
</select>
```

If this helps, or not, please let me know!

Comment: Thanks about that. I don't think though that using `Response.Write` was the problem - I tested using either the suggested `<%For x As Integer = 0 To 5%>` or `Response.Write("<option>" & n.ToString & "</option>")` inside the loop and both ways work.
As soon as `runat="server"` is added, they both do not.

Comment: Just for the record, I did add my listitem-adding code in codebehind and of course it worked, but I still don't understand the initial problem.

Comment: When I add runat="server", this generates a compile error in VS2012 (I tied frameworks 2.0, 3.5 and 4.5). Code blocks are not supported in runat="server" controls.

Comment: I'm still using VS2008.

Comment: I have multiple versions of VS. I tried 2008, 2010, and 2012. All give me the following compile error:
"Code blocks are not supported in this context."
Sorry I cant help on this either.

Comment: Thanks for bothering though! This definitely compiles on my IDE: [link](http://www.paraschis.gr/images/misc/code.png)