# Validate dropdown when value is set to empty using asp.net web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

```
  <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl">
    <asp:ListItem Text="-Select-" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="One" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Two" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Three" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:CompareValidator ID="cvddl" runat="server" Text="Error" 
ControlToValidate="ddl" Operator="NotEqual" ValueToCompare = ""
ValidationGroup="CreateRolls"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

I do want to validate dropdown, if `select` is selected error should be thrown. Main aim is that the value should be empty.

Is there is any methord to validate like this .
Please help me with this

Comment: use required field validator instead of compare validator

Comment: You probably need this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280559/how-to-add-a-requiredfieldvalidator-to-dropdownlist-control

Comment: I have tried that, but error message is not fired

Comment: <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"               runat="server" ErrorMessage="error" ControlToValidate="ddl" InitialValue=""></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

Comment: @VigneshMarteen set the initial value as -select- as you have the initial value as select, and dont forget to use the validation group too..!! You need the validation group in the Submit button too, use same validation group

Comment: you can use my code as it is..! it works fine, i have checked myself..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited answer's Amarnath Balasubramanian (I have not permissions to add comments)

**DropDownList**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server"
                  ValidationGroup="CreateRolls"
                  AppendDataBoundItems="true">
  <asp:ListItem Text="-Select-" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Text="One" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Text="Two" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Text="Three" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**RequiredFieldValidator**

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvDDL" runat="server"
                            ControlToValidate="ddl" 
                            Display="Dynamic"
                            ErrorMessage="Values is required."
                            InitialValue="-1"
                            ForeColor="Red"
                            ValidationGroup="CreateRolls" >
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

The Important property to be noted in the code is the following

```
ControlToValidate="ddl" 
InitialValue="-Select-"
ValidationGroup="CreateRolls"
```

Note that changes are

```
<asp:ListItem Text="-Select-" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
InitialValue="-1"
```

Answer (score 5):

**DropDownList**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server"
                  ValidationGroup="CreateRolls"
                  AppendDataBoundItems="true">
  <asp:ListItem Text="-Select-" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Text="One" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Text="Two" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Text="Three" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**RequiredFieldValidator**

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvDDL" runat="server"
                            ControlToValidate="ddl" 
                            Display="Dynamic"
                            ErrorMessage="Values is required."
                            InitialValue="-Select-"
                            ForeColor="Red"
                            ValidationGroup="CreateRolls" >
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

The Important property to be noted in the code is the following

```
 ControlToValidate="ddl" 
InitialValue="-Select-"
ValidationGroup="CreateRolls"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddRoleType">
<asp:ListItem Text="-Select-" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="One" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Two" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Three" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>



<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" Text="Error" 
ControlToValidate="ddRoleType" Operator="NotEqual" ValueToCompare = "-1"
ValidationGroup="CreateRolls"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

or you can use Required field validator