# Validation Control in ASP.NET form with DropDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation, dropdown

I want to implement validation on drop-down so that at if doesn't select anything, it doesn't allow to submit form. In this program, I am adding a list-item at run time "--Select Package--", which by default is being submitted with -1 value.

DataBase-

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PackageMaster](
        [PackageID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [PackageName] [varchar](50) NULL
    ) ON

 [PRIMARY]

Create Proc UspGetPackage
As
Begin
Select PackageID,PackageName from PackageMaster
End
```

> --------------------------------------------------Design------------------------------

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PackageRequest.aspx.cs" Inherits="PackageRequest" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Select Package:</b></td>&nbsp
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLPackage" runat="server" DataTextField="PackageName" DataValueField="PackageID"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <td><b>Select Sequence:</b></td>&nbsp
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLPakcageSequence" runat="server" DataTextField="SequenceValue" DataValueField="SequenceID"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

> ----------------------CodeBehind---------------

```
private DataSet GetData(string SPName, SqlParameter SPParameter)
{
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SPName, con);
    da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    if (SPParameter != null)
    {
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(SPParameter);
    }

    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(DS);
    return DS;

}



protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DDLPackage.DataSource = GetData("UspGetPackage",null);
            DDLPackage.DataBind();

            ListItem lstPkg = new ListItem("--Select Package--","-1");
            DDLPackage.Items.Insert(0,lstPkg);

            //DDLPakcageSequence.DataSource = GetData("UspGetPkgSequence",null);
            //DDLPakcageSequence.DataBind();

            //ListItem pkgsequence = new ListItem("--Select Sequence--", "-1");
            //DDLPakcageSequence.Items.Insert(0, pkgsequence);
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Use `RequiredFieldValidator` and set `InitialValue` to -1 to avoid default select. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21620315/validate-dropdown-when-value-is-set-to-empty-using-asp-net-web-form)