# Required field validator drop down list asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop down list and Im trying to get a required field validator working for it.

```
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ForeColor="Red" InitialValue="0" ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="dropDownListGender" ErrorMessage="Gender">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>    
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="dd" runat="server" ID="dropDownListGender" >
    <asp:ListItem>Male</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

any ideas wont work and other validation working so not sure whats the problem

Answer (score 0):

By default an HTML select element generated for your ASP.NET DropDownList will have the first element selected.  To work around this see this answer on SO: [How to add a RequiredFieldValidator to DropDownList control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280559/how-to-add-a-requiredfieldvalidator-to-dropdownlist-control)

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do is to use `<asp:comparevalidator>` control like this:

```
    <asp:DropDownList CssClass="dd" runat="server" ID="dropDownListGender" >
        <asp:ListItem>Select Gender</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Male</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:CompareValidator id="cv1" runat="server" controltovalidate="dropDownListGender" 
errormessage="Required" operator="NotEqual" valuetocompare="Select Gender"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

`operator="NotEqual"` will make your job done. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add an initial listitem as below :-

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ForeColor="Red" InitialValue="0" ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="dropDownListGender" ErrorMessage="Gender">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>    
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="dd" runat="server" ID="dropDownListGender" >
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">Please Select</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Male</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```