# Add FieldFalidator so that user selects value from DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have a `Modal Popup` that includes a `DropDownList`, which looks like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListSalesmen" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceSales" DataTextField="FullName" 
    DataValueField="Member_Code" ></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceSales" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SalesConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="usp_NsbGetSalesmen" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The stored procedure that populates this

```
FullName         Member_Code
Select user      0
Joe              1
Jim              2
Mary             3
```

The `modal popup` also includes an *OK* button that's clicked once a user is selected from the list.

I would like to add a validator here, so if the user clicks on "OK" when `Member_Code` equals 0 (item *Select user*) then display a warning message saying that a valid selection has to be made.

What kind of validator should I add here? I prefer doing this validation client-side with the asp.net `Validation` controls.

Thanks.

EDIT: I had tried the link suggested as a duplicate, but the issue was that it would be in a modal popup. For some reason, the solution in the link was not working.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280559/how-to-add-a-requiredfieldvalidator-to-dropdownlist-control).

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownListSalesmen" InitialValue="0" ErrorMessage="Please select valid salesman" />
```